# Can't select Vertex Group for Density field for Geometry node

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-groups

I am following the Donut tutorial and I am up to the geometry node density selection and it doesn't give me the option of selecting the vertex group, when I click to type it comes up blank.

[image]

[image]

I can see the vertex group when I go into:

[image]

(Edit To add that I am clicking the flag and getting blank dropdown box)

[image]

Comment: try clicking on that "norway flag" in the density field, then you should be able to do what you wnt

Comment: Hi, I click that and an empty drop down box appears.

Comment: I actually tried to start the sprinkles again. This time I am getting an error (red line)  when I try and link up the geometry node for group input into the density part of the 'distribute parts on faces' node !

Answer (score 1):

hopefully this works for you:

[image]

so the blend file is totally ok. It might be your Blender version, but i don't think so. Did you click "inside" of the blank black field?

Comment: OMG, well now i feel like an idiot! haha you were right, i wasnt clicking on the space AFTER i had done the flag. i can see it is working now. Thanks for your help! Appreciate your patience with! :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to click on the flag, and then to the black space next to it for the option of my vertex group to come up.

Comment: Afterwards, i redid the tutorial and found that actually I was having the same problem. I was clicking the flag and the dropdown menu was actually blank, so my problem did appear fixed, but it wasnt the above that rectified it. maybe it was just from restarting my laptop? unsure